# 2003 Honda Accord V6 - steering sounds

Tags: honda, power-steering

When I turn the steering wheel more than 30 degrees one way or the other, I start to hear a zzzzhhhhhh sound.

What could be causing the sound? How would I go about diagnosing what is causing the sound.

My steering fluid level is adequate.

**UPDATE**
Recently, I've also noticed that while parking, especially if I put it into reverse, the steering wheel is really hard to turn (more so near the end of the turning range...and it is not due to the fact that my tire is being blocked by the curb).

Comment: You "think" your power steering fluid level is adequate? What makes you think this? Have you checked it properly? Low power steering fluid level would be one of the most likely causes of this noise.

Answer (score 3):

This "MAY" be caused by undue wear on power steering pump.The worst culprit is steering
whilst stationary.Can also cause "scrubbing" of your tyres